# Magento "request timed out" when re indexing

Tags: magento

I have 3 index which are all stuck on "processing". I have tried deleting the files in var/locks, i have tried editing the "connection time" and  the "Memory Limit" in the .htaccess file and also tried running a script call reindex.php, containg this code:

```
<?php  
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';  
 $app = Mage::app('admin');  
 umask(0);  
 for ($index = 7; $index <= 8; $index++) {  
     $process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($index);  
     $process->reindexAll();  
 }
```

However when this code is ran i am still getting the error "request timed out" i really need help as my search isn't working at all and my site is due to go live at the end of the week. Im not the strongest coder in the world and i have seen some fixes suing the command promt however i dont know how to do this so if you are going to advise this, i would appreciate basic step by step guides.

Any help would be very greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance!!!

Comment: please add these two line in your script and then check set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M'); just below the umark(0).

Comment: Please let us know these indexes name in which you are facing issues?

Comment: the index's are 
Catalog URL Rewrites,
Product Flat Data,
Catalog Search Index,
Lucene Search Index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this out

```
<?php
include_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
set_time_limit(0);
ini_set('memory_limit','2048M');
Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);

for ($i = 7; $i <= 8; $i++) 
{
$process = Mage::getModel('index/process')->load($i);
$process->reindexAll();
echo "Reindex done for Process :".$i." out of 11.<br>";
}
?>
```

Comment: Was i meant to put this in my reindex.php file? if so i am still getting the timed out error, thank you for replying though.

Answer (score 1):

Try to truncate catalog_product_flat_1, catalog_product_flat_2, catalog_product_flat_3 so on (if you find in database) in MySQL console or via phpMyAdmin:

```
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_1´;
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_2´;
mysql > truncate table ´catalog_product_flat_3´;
```

Then reindex from admin-panel.

N.S.: please keep backup/export all above mentioned tables before truncate. Mostly it's not effect stores.

OR try this http://www.aurigait.com/blog/Magento-Reindexing-Issue-for-Large-Catalog

Hope this helps you. 
All the best!